# Rails 3, checked radio button with if function

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, radio-button

I have a radio button within my form as follows

```
    <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons-radio">
      <%= f.radio_button :start_year, :class=> "btn", :value=> '2007' %> 2007
      <%= f.radio_button :start_year, :class=> "btn", :value=> '2008' %> 2008
      <%= f.radio_button :start_year, :class=> "btn", :value=> '2009' %> 2009
    </div>
```

I am using twitter bootstrap

I want to do something like the following:

```
    <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons-radio">
      <%= f.radio_button :start_year, :class=> "btn", :value=> '2007', if @dates.start_year == 2007 :checked => true end %> 2007
      <%= f.radio_button :start_year, :class=> "btn", :value=> '2008', if @dates.start_year == 2008 :checked => true end %> 2008
      <%= f.radio_button :start_year, :class=> "btn", :value=> '2009', if @dates.start_year == 2009 :checked => true end %> 2009
    </div>
```

But I get the following error:

```
syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting ')'
syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting ')'
```

I must be making a mistake in the if statement within the radio button, but I'm not sure how exactly to correct this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
<%= f.radio_button :start_year, :class=> "btn", :value=> '2007', :checked => Proc.new { @dates.start_year == 2007 ? true : false } %> 2007
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question, but maybe it helps others.
I don't think we need `Proc` here, we can just pass boolean value to `:checked` key. 
Also, `@dates.start_year == 2007 ? true : false` can be simplified to `@dates.start_year == 2007`.

So, the result will be as simple as

```
<%= f.radio_button :start_year, :value=> '2007', :checked => @dates.start_year == 2007%> 2007
```

Comment: Note - if you are using a tag (instead of f.), they used different syntax (so you have yet another 'magic' pattern to try to memorize).  So for a radio button tag, leave off the ":checked => " and just put a boolean test as the 3rd argument - so: ...  radio_button_tag :start_year, :value=> '2007', (@dates.start_year == 2007)