# Rails - Add class if Radio button is checked

Tags: ruby-on-rails, radio-button, form-for, slim-lang, form-helpers

How to get the value of the radio button from the form_for helper?

Using SLIM.

```
=form_for(@foo) do |f|
  label[class="#{ f.type.value == 'type 1'? 'foo' : 'bar'}"]
    | Type 1
    = f.radio_button :type, 'Type 1' 
  label[class="#{ f.type.value == 'type 2'? 'foo' : 'bar'}"]
    | Type 2
    = f.radio_button :type, 'Type 2'
```

The value method doesnt exist. How to **access** the value of the form helper's radio method?

Comment: have you read the Rails docs?

Comment: @emaillenin no mentioning of accessing the value [Rails](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-radio_button_tag)

Comment: Anyone?.. Really need this..

Answer (score 0):

As per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13208604/rails-3-checked-radio-button-with-if-function), you may be able to use the actual `@foo` variable:

```
label[class="#{ @foo.type == 'type_2'? 'foo' : 'bar'}"]
```